# Convert JSON to CSV in/for Azure

Tags: json, csv, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have JSON files from Google Analytics and like to have them in CSV so they can used by Excel or Power BI.

I´ve stored them in Azure Blob Storage and DocumentDB. Is there a possibility to do this transformation in DocumentDB with the Query Explorer or the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool and a stored procedure? Or are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what transformation you're talking about - can you please elaborate / clarify?

Comment: Transform a JSON file to a CSV file. There a tables with netsted schema stored in *.json files and I like to have only the tables in *.csv files.

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentDB database migration tool supports loading CSV data. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-import-data#a-idcsvaimport-csv-files---convert-csv-to-json

Comment: Thanks. But I´d like to have it the other way around^^ From JSON to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

> I´ve stored them in Azure Blob Storage and DocumentDB. Is there a possibility to do this transformation in DocumentDB with the Query Explorer or the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool and a stored procedure?

As I known, DocumentDB Query Explorer, Store Procedures, User Defined Functions could not transfer JSON to CSV. And the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool could only export your source to a JSON file, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-import-data#export-to-json-file).

> I have JSON files from Google Analytics and like to have them in CSV so they can used by Excel or Power BI.

Based on my understanding, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-powerbi-visualize#flattening-and-transforming-json-documents) to get data from Azure DocumentDB for Power BI. For transfer JSON to CSV, I assumed that you could try to write your transformation logic based on your development language. Or you could leverage [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-documentdb-connector) to move your JSON files from Blob or DocumentDB to Azure Table Storage, then you could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to manage your table and export your records to CSV as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer and the links!